# Can I install Debian from only one DVD?

Tags: debian, bootable-media, unetbootin

When I try to download Debian from the main site, I find 4 DVDs images of 4 GB.

Is it possible to install Debian from only 1 DVD image?

Comment: Yes it is possible. First one will do.

Comment: @Basilevs what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, the first DVD contains most software required for a common workstation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install Debian from just the first DVD. Actually, it is the *preferred* way of doing so, in this sense: The [Debian site](http://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/) states that

> The first CD/DVD disk contains all the files necessary to install a standard Debian system. To avoid needless downloads, please do not download other CD or DVD image files unless you know that you need packages on them.

It is however unusual to need *all* packages on one of the followoing DVD images. You are much better off by installing the first DVD, and then downloading packages as you see fit, without ever needing to download the remaining three DVDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Debian netinst (http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/) image, which is a minimal install, additional packages are downloaded then.

Comment: would, libre office be preinstalled in it?

Comment: Most likely not. Only the required packages to get the OS running and connected to the internet are included, therefor it's a very small image.

Comment: What Browser would i have in that?

Comment: Debian provides 'Iceweasel' by default, which is just Firefox but rebranded due to licensing issues.